# Filling a polygon with lines parallel to its longest side

Tags: python, geometry

Given a list of points that form a polygon, how can I create evenly spaced lines within that polygon that are parallel to it's longest side?

I am able to rotate the lines and get the even spacing, but I can't seem to place them within the polygon. My intention after getting the lines within the polygon is to find where they intercept it.

Here is the point at which I am now stuck:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math


def longest_side(points):
    """
    Returns the points of the longest side
    """
    max_length = 0
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        cur_length = np.linalg.norm(np.array(points[i])-np.array(points[i+1]))
        if cur_length > max_length:
            max_length = cur_length
            cur_longest = [points[i], points[i+1]]
    return cur_longest


def rotate(origin, point, angle):
    """
    Rotate point around origin
    """
    ox, oy = origin
    px, py = point

    qx = ox + math.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - math.sin(angle) * (py - oy)
    qy = oy + math.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + math.cos(angle) * (py - oy)
    return qx, qy


def create_lines(points, spacing):
    """
    Fill polygon with lines
    """
    # Get the longest side
    longest_lines = longest_side(points)
    x1,y1 = longest_lines[0]
    x2,y2 = longest_lines[1]

    # Arrange the points in acending x-value
    if x2 < x1:
        tmp = (x1, y1)
        x1 = x2
        y1 = y2
        x2 = tmp[0]
        y2 = tmp[1]

    # Get the angle between the longest line and the horizontal axis
    angle = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
    
    # Create lines parallel to the longest line with given spacing
    for y in np.arange(min(y1, y2), max(y1, y2), spacing):
        xr, yr = rotate(origin=[min(x), y], point=[max(x), y], angle=angle)
        plt.plot([min(x), xr], [y, yr])
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    points = ([0, 8], [2, 10], [10, 4], [10, 0], [0, 8])

    x = [p[0] for p in points]
    y = [p[1] for p in points]

    create_lines(points=points, spacing=1)

    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro-')
    plt.axis('scaled')

    plt.show()
```

Is there a general way this problem can be solved given any list of points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: you need to do some geometry.

The long answer:

1. Create a Line Segment class to easily calculate line intersections and acceptable range of intercepts of lines with fixed slope m that still intersect with the line segment.
2. Turn your points into Line Segments, find the longest line, find the range of intercepts needed to fill the polygon, then find the intersections for each line generated by each intercept.

Class definition:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

# Represent a non-vertical line segment from start_pt to end_pt
# as y = mx + b and minv <= x <= maxv. 
# For vertical lines x = b, m = None and minv <= y <= maxv
class LineSeg():
    
    def __init__(self, start_pt, end_pt):
        
        self.x, self.y = start_pt
        self.x2, self.y2 = end_pt
        
        if self.x != self.x2:
            self.m = (self.y2 - self.y) / (self.x2 - self.x)
            self.b = self.y - self.m*self.x
            
            self.minv = min(self.x, self.x2)
            self.maxv = max(self.x, self.x2)
            
        else:
            self.m = None
            self.b = self.x
            self.minv = min(self.y, self.y2)
            self.maxv = max(self.y, self.y2)
            
    def length(self):
        return np.linalg.norm([self.x2-self.x, self.y2-self.y])
        
        
    # Find intersection (x, y) with line y = mx + b    
    def intersect_w_line(self, m, b):
        # Parallel lines
        if m == self.m:
            return (None, None)
        
        # Line is vertical but line segment is not
        elif m == None:
            if self.minv <= b <= self.maxv:
                return (b, self.m*b + self.b)
            else:
                return (None, None)
            
        # Line segment is vertical, but line is not
        elif self.m == None:
            y = m*self.b + b
            
            if self.minv <= y <= self.maxv:
                return (self.b, y)
            else:
                return (None, None)
            
        else:
            
            x = (b - self.b) / (self.m - m)
            y = self.m*x + self.b
            
            if self.minv <= x <= self.maxv:
                return (x, y)
            else:
                return (None, None)
            
    # Find intercept range with line y = mx + b
    def intercept_range(self, m):
        
        if self.m == m:
            return (self.b, self.b)
        
        # Line is vertical, but segment is not
        elif m == None:
            return sorted([self.x, self.x2])
        
        # Line is not vertical
        else:
            b = self.y - m*self.x
            b2 = self.y2 - m*self.x2
            
            return sorted([b, b2])
```

Plotting:

```
points = ([0, 8], [2, 10], [10, 4], [10, 0])
linesegs = [LineSeg(points[i], points[i+1]) if i+1 < len(points) else LineSeg(points[i], points[0]) for i in range(len(points))]
lengths = [lineseg.length() for lineseg in linesegs]
longest_seg = [lineseg for lineseg in linesegs if lineseg.length() == max(lengths)]
m = longest_seg[0].m
b = longest_seg[0].b

intercept_ranges = [lineseg.intercept_range(m) for lineseg in linesegs]

max_intercept = np.max(intercept_ranges)
min_intercept = np.min(intercept_ranges)

num_lines = 10

spacing = (max_intercept - min_intercept) / (num_lines+1)

intercepts = np.arange(min_intercept + spacing, max_intercept, spacing)

line_pts = [[lineseg.intersect_w_line(m, intercept) for lineseg in linesegs if lineseg.intersect_w_line(m, intercept)[0] is not None] for intercept in intercepts]

plt.close('all')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

polygon = mpl.patches.Polygon(points, closed = True, fill = False)

ax.add_artist(polygon)

for start, end in line_pts:
    line = mpl.lines.Line2D([start[0], end[0]], [start[1], end[1]])
    ax.add_artist(line)

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
```

Comment: Wow, this is great, thanks! It's nice to be able the set the number of lines within the polygon, but I would also like to just specify the spacing width between the lines, then let the algorithm figure out how many lines to fit in it. Is it as easy as just setting the spacing variable you defined to whatever width i desire?

Comment: Roughly. The spacing variable is the spacing between intercepts (y-intercepts for non-vertical lines, x-intercept for vertical lines), so the spacing between lines is the sine of the angle if I'm doing my geometry right.